# Everybody knows how to make a child

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Imagine a parent have several impolite and rude children who make lots of problems. Once one of the children who is a teenager makes a bad problem for their neighbor who is a middle aged man. It drives him crazy and he goes to their house and calls his father. He says:

> - **Everybody knows how to make a child.** What is important is the way you raise up a child. It requires lots of care.

Does the bold part above sound idiomatic and natural to a native speaker? If not what shall I use instead to make myself understood in a natural way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Everybody knows how to make a child.

This sounds like you are concerned with who knows how to make a child, rather than the ability to make children itself.  Which makes this sound weird since there is an actual "already made" child that is part of the situation - it almost sounds like you are accusing them of not knowing how to make a child.

> Anyone can make a child

is more what you are trying to say.  Relating the two clauses with an explicit *but* will make it very clear.

> Anyone can make a child, but what's important is the way you raise up that child.